# Recursive Multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion

I'm creating a function that searches through a directory, prints out files, and when it runs into a folder, a new thread is created to run through that folder and do the same thing.

It makes sense to me to use recursion then as follows:

```
pthread_t tid[500];
int i = 0;

void *search(void *dir)
{
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *df;
    df = opendir(dir)

    char curFile[100];

    while ((dp = readdir(df)) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(curFile, "%s/%s",dir,dp->d_name);

        if(isADirectory(curFile))
        {
            pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &search, &curFile);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", curFile);
        }
    }
    pthread_join(&tid[i])

    return 0;
}
```

When I do this, however, the function ends up trying to access directories that don't actually exist. Initially I had pthread_join() directly after pthread_create(), which worked, but I don't know if you can count that as multithreading since each thread waits for its worker thread to exit before doing anything.

Is the recursive aspect of this problem even possible, or is it necessary for a new thread to call a different function other than itself?

Comment: Little knows fact while(1){fork()} is not recursive multi threading ... those are processes

Comment: Most likely you have shared, mutating state which is causing the confusion. Without you providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to tell for sure. At least show the declaration of `curFile` and any mutations of what it points to.

Comment: Also, `i++` is not atomic and so is prone to a race hazard. Try making `tid` and `i` method local.

Comment: @davmac If `tid` and `i` are local, won't they always reset back to zero in the worker thread's `search()` function? Thus making them useless?

Comment: @davmac: `pthread_create(&tid[i++], NULL, &search, &curFile)` would probably solve the race.

Comment: @wildplasser No, it would not.

Comment: @NYB as I see it the purpose of `tid` is to hold the thread ids that we need to `join` on before 'this' directory (or specifically, its subdirectories) have been scanned. `i` is an index into `tid` which is incremented each time we spawn a new thread to scan a subdirectory. It's fine that each thread has its own instance, because they are specific to the particular directory being searched (and each thread deals with only one). I don't see why `i` starting at 0 for each new thread would be a problem.

Comment: Bottleneck of this search process is the magnetic head in the disk drive. There's only one of it per disk, and it takes great deal of time for that head to move from one place on the disk to another (millions times more than it takes to execute code). Introducing more threads to the algorithm will make this head move around without doing actual work and will most likely slow down the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your `while` loop. Inside it you have:

```
   sprintf(curFile, "%s/%s",dir,dp->d_name);
```

and

```
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &search, &curFile);
```

So, you *mutate* the contents of `curFile` inside the loop, and you also create a thread which you are trying to pass the *current* contents of `curFile`. This is a spectacular race hazard - there is no guarantee that the new thread will see the intended contents of `curFile`, since it may have changed in the meantime. You need to duplicate the string and pass the new thread a copy which won't be mutated by the calling thread. The thread is therefore also going to have be responsible for deallocating the copy, which means either that the `search` method do exactly that or that you have a second method.

You have another race condition in using `i` and `tid` in all threads. As I have suggested in the comment on your question, I think these variables should be method local.

In general I suggest that you read on thread safety and learn about data race hazards before you attempt to use threads. It is usually best to avoid the use of threads unless you *really* need the extra performance.

Comment: Actually, you could store pointers to the curFile strings for each thread in another (method local) array and free them after the `pthread_join`, rather than have the thread you create be responsible for de-allocating the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dealt with multithreading in a while but if memory serves threads share resources. Which means (in your example) every new thread you make accesses the same variable "i". Now if those threads only read variable "i" there would be no problem whatsoever (every thread keeps reading ... i = 2 wohoo :D).

But issues arise when threads share resources that are being read and written on.

```
i = 2
i++
// there are many threads running this code 
// and "i" is shared among them, are you sure i = 3?
```

Read, write on shared resources problem is solved with thread synchronization. I recommend reading/googling upon it since it's a pretty unique topic to be solved in one question.

P.S. I pointed out variable "i" in your code but there may be more such resources since your code doesn't display any attempt at thread synchronization.